# How to add validations for formik form with material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I am new to the formik and I am trying to add validations .

I have container which is like :

```
export default class ForgotPasswordContainer extends React.Component<
  RouteComponentProps,
  MyState
> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      error: '',
      success: ''
    }
  }
  forgotPasswordSuccess = async result => {
    if (result.Status === 'Successful') {
      this.setState({
        success: strings.emailSuccess
      })
    } else if (result.Status === 'Failed') {
      this.setState({
        error: result.ErrorAdmin
      })
    }
  }

  forgotPassword = async ({ variables }) => {
    console.log(variables)
    const url = `url to change password`
    console.log(url)
    try {
      const result: any = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          Accept: 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          mode: 'no-cors'
        }
      })

      return {
        data: {
          login: await result.json()
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      this.setState({
        error:
          err?.response?.data?.error_description || err.message || strings.genericError
      })
      throw err
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { forgotPassword, forgotPasswordSuccess } = this
    return (
      <ForgotPasswordPage
        onSubmit={forgotPassword}
        error={this.state.error}
        onForgotPasswordSuccess={forgotPasswordSuccess}
        OnSuccess={this.state.success}
        backgroundImage={LoginBackground}
        logo={logo}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Now in the `ForgotPasswordPage` component

```
((withFormik as any)({
  mapPropsToValues: () => ({ username: '' })
  validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
    username: Yup.string().required('Username is required!')
  }),
  handleSubmit: (values, { setSubmitting, props }) => {
    const { onSubmit, onForgotPasswordSuccess } = props
    onSubmit({ variables: values }).then(
      result => {
        setSubmitting(false)        
        onForgotPasswordSuccess(result.data.login)
      },
      () => {
        setSubmitting(false)
      }
    )
  },
  displayName: 'LoginForm'
}))
export default class ForgotPasswordPage extends React.Component<MyProps> {
  render() {
    const {
      error,
      values,
      touched,
      errors,
      dirty,
      isSubmitting,
      handleChange,
      handleBlur,
      handleSubmit,
      logo,
      headerLabel,
      backgroundImage,
      OnSuccess
    } = this.props
    return (
      <Card
        style={{ background: `url(${backgroundImage})` }}
        className={css.backgroundCard}
        alignItem='center'
        justifyContent='center'>
        <Card
          className={css.loginCard}
          variant='standard'
          alignItem='center'
          direction='column'>
          {logo ? (
            <Icon imageSrc={logo} className={css.logo} />
          ) : (
            <div>
              <div>
                <Typography variant='h1'>{headerLabel}</Typography>
              </div>
              <div>
                <Typography variant='h1'>Forgot Password</Typography>
              </div>
            </div>
          )}
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className={css.loginForm}>
            <Input
              variant='standard'
              textAlign='center'
              placeholder='Username'
              id='username'
              name='username'
              type='text'
              value={values.username}
              onChange={handleChange}
              onBlur={handleBlur}
              autoFocus
              error={errors.username && touched.username}
            />

            {error && (
              <Typography variant='caption' classes={css.errorMsg}>
                {error}
              </Typography>
            )}

            {OnSuccess && (
              <Typography variant='caption' classes={css.successMsg}>
                {OnSuccess}
              </Typography>
            )}

            <Button
              variant='primary'
              theme='light'
              type='submit'
              disabled={!dirty || isSubmitting || !!errors.username}>
              <Typography variant='h1'>Send Password</Typography>
            </Button>
          </form>
        </Card>
      </Card>
    )
  }
}
```

Now Here in this form I am trying to do few things like

adding validations , such that password and repeat password should be same
and that is required . on Success of onSummit clear form.

How to add the validations in this form ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use `yup` library https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup. The library works well with formik, here you can see how to build easy validation form.

https://formik.org/docs/guides/validation

Answer (score 0):

You can update `validationSchema`like this:

```
  validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
    username: Yup.string().required('Username is required!'),
    password: Yup.string()
      .min(7)
      .max(255)
      .required("Password is required"),
    confirmPassword: Yup.string()
      .min(7)
      .max(255)
      .oneOf([Yup.ref("password")], "Password's not match")
      .required("Required!"),
  })
```

Comment: So the key for the object will be the one which we will use in the template  ?

Comment: Also everytime it says username is reqired, How to  set initial value to empty string in the given form example

Comment: thanks for answer, But I am not sure how do show the error message "Password's not match" using which key..

Comment: the error message will be in the `errors` props. So you can use `FormHelperText` of Material-UI to show this error

Comment: Yes @Viet , the only thing is when I tried doing errors.password their I am getting an error for that particular field which says password is required,  So, what I am trying is the error when the password does not matches , That error I want to show, For that which errors field I should use ?

Comment: any solution on the above /